# how to use webpack to split angularjs controller.js ? it's too long.i want to split with every page.This is my smallest file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

This is my controller, I plan to split from the simplest

```
console.log('load document');


angular.module('app').controller('document', function ($scope, ItemService, UserService, ScopeService, $timeout, $q, $compile, $location, $route, $ocLazyLoad, $routeParams) {

    $scope.$emit('changeTitle', 'document');
    let itemService = ItemService();
    let userService = UserService();
    let scopeService = ScopeService();

    let documentModel = itemService.document();
    let userModel = userService.user();
    let htmlModel = itemService.html();

    let html = { reportDoc: '', deleteForm: '', };
    let users = []
    let reportDoc = {};

    $scope.docArray = [];
    /**
     *  createReport page
     */
    let createReportDocObj = ScopeService('createReport') || scopeService.initialize('createReport', $('#background_document'), function () {
        let report = '';
        return _.template(html.reportDoc)({ report: report })
    }, false);

    $scope.createDoc = function () {
        createReportDocObj.compile(true, {});
        reportDocObj.scope.isLoading = false;
        initEditor();
    }

    /**
     *  show report page
     */
    let reportDocObj = ScopeService('reportDoc') || scopeService.initialize('reportDoc', $('#background_document'), function () {
        if (reportDocObj.scope.isLoading) return html.reportDoc
        reportDocObj.scope.changed = false;
        if (reportDoc.content === undefined) return;
        let report = reportDoc.content.html;
        return _.template(html.reportDoc)({ report: report })
    }, false);

    reportDocObj.scope.save = function () {
    }
    reportDocObj.scope.checkSave = function () {
    }

    reportDocObj.scope.download = function (editor) {
    }
    $scope.getDocument = function (id) {
    }
    /**
     *  check page
     */
    let checkSaveReportObj = ScopeService('checkSaveReport') || scopeService.initialize('checkSaveReport', $('#background_report'), function (args) {
        return _.template(html.checkSave)(args);
    }, false);
    checkSaveReportObj.scope.submit = function () {
    }
    checkSaveReportObj.scope.cancel = function () {
    }

    /**
     * deleteReport page
     */
    let deleteReportObj = ScopeService('deleteReport') || scopeService.initialize('deleteReport', $('#background_report'), function (args) {
        return _.template(html.deleteForm)(args);
    }, false);

    deleteReportObj.doc_id = undefined;
    $scope.deleteDoc = function (id) {
    }
    deleteReportObj.scope.submit = function () {
    }


    let url = 'static/html/testcase/document_temp.html';
    let queue = [documentModel.list(), userModel.list(), htmlModel.get(url)];
    $q.all(queue).then(function (result) {
        $scope.docArray = result[0].data;
        users = result[1].data;
        html = itemService.htmlArray[url];


    }).catch(function (reason) {
    });
});
```

I hope that the code can be divided into shorter and easier to maintain. Because it is too long. I don't know how to reference my scope and service in the divided file
There are too many projects in this project, so I plan to start refactoring from the controller

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend webpack to do for you here. Webpack's primary purpose is to optimize performance and size of code for deployment, not for generating human-readable code. It can theoretically be configured in such a way, but the effort involved implies you should probably just refactor it the old-fashioned way. Also, the code you provided is 89 lines long; so unless you're omitting the function bodies and they are long, this raises concerns around the genuity of this question.

Comment: i ignore .This is my simplest controller, with thousands of lines of code.

Comment: Most of them are thousands of lines. Many functions are put into a controller.This project needs to add and modify functions frequently. So I want to change from the simplest part first

Comment: It sounds like what you are looking for is a JS module system which webpack can help you utilize. Getting an large, existing angularjs project to use modules can be an enormous undertaking and doing it as part of a migration to modern Angular (or another modern JS framework if you like) would likely be time better spent. I wish I could better advise, but cleaning up a monolithic AngularJS project with thousand line controllers is challenging and the path to achieve maintainability depends on many factors.